# Unable to limit number of Cloud Run instances spun up by Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, autoscaling, google-cloud-run

Situation:
I'm trying to have a single message in Pub/Sub processed by exactly 1 instance of Cloud Run. Additional messages will be processed by another instance of Cloud Run. Each message triggers a  heavy computation that runs for around 100s in the Cloud Run instance.

Currently, Cloud Run is configured with max concurrency requests = 1, and min/max instances of 0/5. Subscription is set to allow for 600s Ack deadline.

Issue:
Each message seems to be triggering multiple instances of Cloud Run to be spun up. I believe that it is due to high CPU utilization that's causing Cloud Run to spin up additional instances to help process. Unfortunately, these new instances are attempting to process the same exact message, causing unintented results.

Question:
Is there a way to force Cloud Run to only have 1 instance process a single message, regardless of CPU utilization and other potential factors?

Relevant Code Snippet:

```
import base64
import json

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
async def handleMessage(request: Request):

  envelope = await request.json()

  # Basic data validation
  if not envelope:
      msg = "no Pub/Sub message received"
      print(f"error: {msg}")
      return Response(content=msg, status_code=400)

  if not isinstance(envelope, dict) or "message" not in envelope:
      msg = "invalid Pub/Sub message format"
      print(f"error: {msg}")
      return Response(content=msg, status_code=400)

  message = envelope["message"]

  if isinstance(message, dict) and "data" in message:
      data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(message["data"]).decode("utf-8").strip())

  try:
      # Do computationally heavy operations here
      # Will run for about 100s

      return Response(status_code=204)

  except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Cloud Run process requests. PubSub push subscription create one request per message. High computation of not, it's not a problem for Cloud Run, because you can process only 1 message per instance (concurrency setting), but Cloud Run can start/pre-provision other instances in advance because of the current instance usage. Anyway, if your message is processed several time,it's because it's not Ack by CLoud Run. Return a HTTP code 200 for that. If you do it, share your code (only useful part) to let us test and help you

Comment: My main issue here is that multiple instances of Cloud Run is processing the same message. I sent 2 messages to Pub/Sub for testing, and i see > 2 instances of Cloud Run spun up, and the messages processed >2 times

Comment: That's strange. Did you log the message ID? Are you sure that is the same message?

Comment: I just did. 2 messages sent through Pub/Sub, 4 Cloud Run instances spun up. The 2 messages' messageIds got logged a total of 4 times (twice for each unique messageId)

Comment: How many subscription do you have?

Comment: 1 push subscription on the topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the issue.

Apparently, Pub/Sub guarantees "at least once" delivery, which means it is possible for it to deliver a message to a subscriber more than once. The onus is therefore on the subscriber, which in my case is Cloud Run, to handle such scenarios (idempotency) gracefully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).